# Required disabled input type field makes form dirty and invalid

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-form

I have conditional html form and I conditionally disabled input type fields through ng-disabled and in submit button use ng-disabled="formName.$invalid".....but disabled required fields makes form dirty and invalid. So how do I approach validation with conditional form?

Comment: Do you want to make the fields enabled before submitting?

Comment: No  I don;t want to make them enabled but dirty and invalid property of form stops me to submit form

Comment: On top of the form give <form name="myForm" novalidate></form>

Comment: whatever fields you see in form are required so i can't put novalidate.

Comment: <form name="Demo">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" required/>
     <span ng-show="Demo.fname.$dirty && Demo.fname.$error.required">First Name  is required.</span>
  <br />
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="lname" required ng-disabled="true"/>
     <span ng-show="Demo.lname.$dirty && Demo.lname.$error.required">Last Name  is required.</span>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="Demo.$invalid"/>
</form>